# Jquery $(this) is not working

Tags: jquery, css, input, this

I have this code

```
    if($('input[type="text"]').val() == ''){
        $(this).css('width', '20%');
        }
```

HTML

```
<input id="id_nombre" maxlength="100" name="nombre" placeholder="Inserte su nombre" type="text">
<input id="id_email" maxlength="150" name="email" placeholder="Inserte su E-Mail" type="text">
```

That doesnt work but if I write the input instead of this it works. Seems like this is pointing to the whole html

Comment: Can you post the whole function, please?

Comment: Ok, where's the HTML you're working with?

Comment: Well, what does `this` point to?

Comment: `this` won't be the value that you think it is. It doesn't switch to become the input you reference in the if block. If you run `console.log(this)`. inside the if you can see exactly what it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add CSS by targeting the empty input with the use of the jQuery filter function

```
jQuery("input[type="text"]").filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
}).css('width', '20%');
```

This will add the CSS to all inputs with type text and an empty value.

Answer (score 5):

`$(this)` refers to the caller of the outermost scope of your function, which is probably your document or some other container (hard to tell without context). An `if` block does not change this, though an `each` will.

If you want to prevent duplication, feel free to assign the jQuery object to a variable:

```
var input = $('input[type="text"]');
if (input.val() == '') {
    input.css('width', '20%');
}
```

Edit: Since you have multiple inputs, you'll get your desired behavior by using an `each` loop:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).css('width', '20%');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ohh u right :/ noob mistake , i want to change the class on the inputs that are empty , if i want to execute the code when the form is sent how would i do it ?

Comment: You can use an `each` loop in your submit function. See my edit.

Comment: But that also runs when i first enter the page :/

Comment: Then you'll have to move it to another function somewhere in your Javascript, wherever you want it to run.

Comment: Is there something like a document ready but for reload or form request ?